# Upgrade Galaxy S Advance from 2.3 to 4.1

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, updates, 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-advance

I have the Samsung Galaxy S Advance which is currently running Android version 2.3, can I upgrade it to Android 4.1?

I googled and found [this](http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/articles/424263/20130115/root-galaxy-s-advance-android412-xxlpy-jellybean.htm) It is telling that I need a rooted phone. What does this mean?

Is there high possibility of any problem?

Comment: That link is telling you how to root a device that is already running ICS, not how to upgrade from GB to ICS.

Comment: Have you forced your phone to check for an update? What country are you located? According to [this article](http://www.android.gs/update-galaxy-s-advance-i9070-official-jelly-bean-4-1-2-xxlq4/) Austria, Belgium, France, Germany, Hungry, Italy, Russia, Spain, and the UK have rolled out the OTA upgrade.